# How to send Notification to a mobile when a specific changes is happens on database?

Tags: android, notifications

Ian newbie to the android mobile app. 
I need to send a notification for a user when a new ticket is opened for him in a database that means when a new ticket is inserted in the ticket table I should send a notification to the user till him that.
**Please note that tickets open from a web application and the notification need to send to a mobile app.**
it should be a realtime app.
please note that I have an existing database on SQL server.

I tried to used the job scheduler to send a notification to the user by calling a web service each one minute and if the new ticket is inserted then send a notification the problem with this solution is battery consuming and it's not considered as a real-time app.

Comment: The server has to send a cloud message, the server knows when the insert happens after it triggers the cloud message and send it to the device. Search for FCM or LeanPlum

Comment: thank you for your answer can you provide me with more details, please.
please note that the ticket opens from the web application and the notification should be sent to the mobile app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is creating web API which send push notification using the "app center" to users. then in the database create a trigger which calls this web service when a new ticket is inserted.
by this solution, I don't care from where this ticket is opened from mobile or web or any other way.